# scrollView setContentOffset crashes when accessing method from another file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a HomeView class with scrollView IBOutlet and a function the changes the offset of the scrollView:

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width * 2, y: 0), animated: true)
```

From the FeedView class I attempt:

```
let Home = HomeView()
Home.ScrollRight()
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: this is wrong !! Why you are trying to do so ? ,  You are creating New instance of  `HomeView`

Comment: I have multiple view controllers sub viewed for a page style navigation and want to have a button to scroll. How do I access the function without creating a new instance of HomeView?

Comment: Could you pls add some more code that could be easy to encounter

Answer (score 1):

Because your `HomeView` created by either XIB or Story board. Thats why below line return `nil` object.

```
let Home = HomeView()
```

If you want to call `ScrollRight()` method of `HomeView` from another class then declare global variable of `HomeView` like

```
var homeVC = HomeView()
```

and in `viewDidMethod` of `HomeView`

```
homeVC = self as HomeView
```

not you can access `homeVC` from anywhere

and just call method by

```
homeVC.ScrollRight()
```

from another viewController.

=======================================
**EX**

```
import UIKit
var homeVC = HomeVC()

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        homeVC = self as HomeVC
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Now you can use `homeVC` object and access property of `HomeVC` anywhere.

**NOTE:**
If you are calling function from same viewController *(HomeView)* then you don't need to create object of that viewController. You can just simply call function by below like directly.

`ScrollRight()` OR `self.ScrollRight()`

Comment: In HomeView where you have "homeVC = self as HomeView" I get an error of unidentified homeVC

Comment: Did you declare "var homeVC = HomeView()' at below  of  "import" statement of "HomeView" ?

Comment: @ChrisRichards - Check my updated answer, I made one demo for you and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your scroll view is set up as an outlet it means it is created within your view controller's main view when said view controller is **instantiated from a storyboard**.

This code:

```
let Home = HomeView()
```

...at most instantiates the view controller itself, but it does not load its view (let alone wire the outlets to the appropriate subviews -in this case, your scroll view).

Please read about view controller view life cycle. It's all in Apple's programming guides and countless tutorials online.